# optimising and increasing the design

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

So this question is not oriented on a specific problem I was just wondering if there is a designer out there that could help me make my app look better. So here is the image[image: phone]

Comment: I guess you'll find more designers on a site which is not primarily about writing code. Like for example [UX stack exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: please add an example would be appreciated ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Something like this ?

[image]

For starters if you want to include the different sections for the questions and answers try using contrasting colors or just using one solid/gradient background for the whole view.

Or alternatively like I did use cards and have single background for them, play with the button design a bit try borders / no borders / hover-state or just simple background

Secondly FONTS, these play a very big role in UX and UI, keep them simpler and consistent. But if you have to, try no more than 2 types of fonts.

And I did a few indicators to the bottom to indicate which question they are on.

Lastly don't rush the user with a plethora of things, the lesser to interact the easier to use and work around.

I hope this helps you.